# Attribute table not updating after QGIS field calculator used?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

Using QGIS 2.8.1 i am trying to update an attribute table using the field calculator.  its a vector layer of vegetation communities.  i am trying to update the area fields in the table.  The output example in the calculator shows a correct calculation, but the areas do not update and stay as 0.0000.  The field is "real" 10 wide with a precision of 4.

Any ideas on why the table does not update?

Comment: Is the layer editable? If you change one area value manually, does it get saved?

Comment: In a very rare occasions I've experienced same issue - turned out it's only that table display wasn't updated not the values itself. Try update the table in any way - for example sort data by any field.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  I closed the program and re-opened sometime later and the problem did not occur.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a shapefile or any other type of file, try saving it to a new file, maybe the file itsself is somehow corrupt.